# PHP Why does my html display as text?

Tags: php, html, text

I'm learning php and trying do to form that I mail to my email. This my code:

```
  $to = "name@domain.com";
  $subject = "Competition Entry - WIN A 2 NIGHT FAMILY PRICE";
  $message = "Name: ".$name. "<br />" ."Surname: ".$surname.;
  mail ($to, $subject, $message);
  ?>
```

When it sends to my email it display as:

```
Name:  <br /> Surname:
```

Why does my `<br />` display as text and not as a break?

Comment: Maybe your email client disabled HTML view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send proper headers is you need to send mail with html:

```
 $header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
 $to      = "name@domain.com";
 $subject = "Competition Entry - WIN A 2 NIGHT FAMILY PRICE";
 $message = "Name: ".$name. "<br />" ."Surname: ".$surname.;
 mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Thank you I will go do more research on headers :)

Answer (score 3):

Append header `Content-Type`

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

**Example Document Sending Mail With HTML Format :** http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: `ISO-8859-1` - really? :)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski utf-8 for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because your mail body is plain text by default and `<br />` is HTML tag. If you want to send mail in HTML, you need to build it properly (I suggest you use `PHPMailer` class to do the job). If you want just line break. you need to use `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Start using [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), your life will be easier.

```
require_once('swift/lib/swift_required.php');
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setFrom(array($from))
    ->setTo(array($to))
    ->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get7BitEncoding())
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->setBody($body, 'text/html')
    ->addPart(strip_tags($body), 'text/plain')
    ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($filename))
;
$mailer->send($message);
```